# How do I remove the second character from a string?

Tags: ruby, string

If I want to remove last character from a string, then I simply use

```
'string'[0..-1]
```

But how do I remove the second character from a string?

Comment: I do not want to vote down because I don't wanna be mean, but did you even think about it? Or did you read any book or documentation?

Comment: `'string'[0..-1]` doesn't remove the character. It returns all characters up to the end of the string. `'string'[0..-1] => "string"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean remove the second character and keep the rest of the string.

hello => hllo

`s[0].chr+s[2..-1]`

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is

```
str[1] = ''   #1.9.3
```

or

```
str[1,1] = '' #1.8.7
```

I am not sure if it will work in Jruby because it has different way of manipulating string. If it does not work, use @Finbarr 's method and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the question **How** it may be important to now which is the **fastest** method.

I made a benchmark with the other answers and with a solution with slice! and `sub!`.

```
require 'benchmark'
N = 100_000 #Number of Test loop

STR = '0123456789'

REGEXP = /\A(.)./
Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('str[0].chr+str[2..-1]') { N.times { 
        str = STR.dup
        str = str[0].chr+str[2..-1]
      }}
  b.report('str[1]') { N.times { 
        str = STR.dup
        str[1] = ''
      }}
  b.report('slice!') { N.times { 
        str = STR.dup
        str.slice!(1)
      }}          
  b.report('sub!') { N.times { 
        str = STR.dup
        str.sub!(/\A(.)./, '\1')
      }}          
  b.report('sub!/REGEXP') { N.times { 
        str = STR.dup
        str.sub!(REGEXP, '\1')  #Avoid reinitialization of regex for each loop
      }}
} #Benchmark
```

My results (windows, Ruby 1.9.3)

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------------
str[0].chr+str[2..-1]   0.203000   0.000000   0.203000 (  0.171875)
str[1]                  0.094000   0.000000   0.094000 (  0.109375)
slice!                  0.094000   0.000000   0.094000 (  0.125000)
sub!                    0.250000   0.016000   0.266000 (  0.265625)
sub!/REGEXP             0.265000   0.016000   0.281000 (  0.234375)
------------------------------------------------ total: 0.938000sec

                            user     system      total        real
str[0].chr+str[2..-1]   0.188000   0.000000   0.188000 (  0.171875)
str[1]                  0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.109375)
slice!                  0.172000   0.000000   0.172000 (  0.125000)
sub!                    0.218000   0.015000   0.233000 (  0.265625)
sub!/REGEXP             0.282000   0.000000   0.282000 (  0.250000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sin = 'string'
sout = sin[0] + sin[2..-1]
```